# "SDK-buildable" Open Source Web Browsers for Android

Tags: android, open-source, browser

I am trying to build a comprehensive list of known **non-AOSP** open source web browsers for the Android, from which fellow programmers and I can learn-by-example.

By **non-AOSP** I mean that it can be built outside of the full firmware build.

The stock Android browser is probably the best exemplary browser but unfortunately it [cannot be built](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5293110/android-the-type-java-lang-enum-cannot-be-resolved/5293163#5293163) outside of the full firmware build.

The ability to build such apps in a regular Android SDK development environment is important for those who learn best by experimenting with code modifications.

Google search for [open source browsers for android](http://www.google.com/#hl=en&sugexp=ldymls&xhr=t&q=open+source+browsers+for+android&cp=32&pf=p&sclient=psy&aq=f&aqi=&aql=&oq=open+source+browsers+for+android&pbx=1&bav=on.2,or.r_gc.r_pw.&fp=eec7b1769f792670) yields disappointing results, so perhaps we can come up with a more focused result. Links to actual source code repository would be super.

So far, I managed to find the following:

1. [Fennec (aka Mobile Firefox)](https://wiki.mozilla.org/Mobile/Platforms/Android) --
   source code [here](https://wiki.mozilla.org/Mobile/Fennec/Android#Download_Source_Code).
2. [Memento-browser](http://code.google.com/p/memento-browser/) - -- source
   code [here](http://code.google.com/p/memento-browser/downloads/detail?name=MementoBrowser1.2.zip&can=2&q=).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is experimental but I've learned and took some ideas from it:

http://code.google.com/p/mosembro/

Answer (score 4):

Browsers found in [F-Droid repository](https://f-droid.org), collected from other answers and from other sources:

## Active projects

### [GApps Sandboxed Browser](https://github.com/tobykurien/GoogleNews)

Last updated: February 2014
License: MIT

It's not fully functional browser, just browser dedicated to browse Google services.

### [geckobrowser](https://github.com/mfinkle/geckobrowser)

Last updated: July 2014
License: Mozilla Public License, v. 2.0

It' very, very, very simple demonstration of how to use [GeckoView](https://wiki.mozilla.org/Mobile/GeckoView) - WebView replacement that use Gecko rendering engine.

### [Lightning Browser](https://github.com/anthonycr/Lightning-Browser)

Last updated: July 2014
License:  Mozilla Public License, v. 2.0

#### Features

- bookmarks
- history
- find in page
- integrated multiple search engines (Google, Bing, Yahoo, StartPage, DuckDuckGo, etc.)
- incognito mode
- flash support (prior to 4.4)
- Google search suggestions
- Orbot Proxy support
- **simple, domain-based AdBlock**
- navigation using tabs in left drawer and bookmarks in right drawer

### [Lucid Browser](https://github.com/powerpoint45/Lucid-Browser)

Last updated: July 2014
License: MIT

- bookmarks
- **no history**
- find in page
- navigation using tabs and menu in right drawer
- pleasing design

### [Memento Browser](https://code.google.com/p/memento-browser/)

Last updated: January 2014
License: Apache License 2.0

Experimental browser for web.archive.org and similar services that archive webpages

### [Orfox](https://github.com/guardianproject/Orfox)

Last updated: July 2014
License: GPL version 2

Basically same as Orweb (see below), but use GeckoView instead of WebView.

### [Orweb](https://github.com/guardianproject/orweb)

Last updated: July 2014
License: GPL version 2 (browser), Mozilla Public License 2.0 (GeckoView components)

> Proxy-capable and Privacy-aware Web Browser for use with Orbot's localhost 8118 proxy, or any HTTP proxy server.

Simple browser for anonymous browsing. Needs [Orbot](https://gitweb.torproject.org/orbot.git) or other proxy installed and configured.

### [Tint Browser](https://github.com/Anasthase/TintBrowser)

Last updated: January 2014
License: GPL version 3

- **multiple UI type: phone and tablet**
- bookmarks
- **no history**
- find in page
- integrated multiple search engines (Google, StartPage, DuckDuckGo, Wikipedia)
- incognito mode
- flash support
- **a few addons, including AdBlock, installed seprarately**
- navigation using tabs in left drawer
- option to redirect javascript logs to logcat

## Stale projects

- [Mosembro](https://code.google.com/p/mosembro/) - last updated October 2009

  > Mosembro is an experimental webkit based browser for Android mobile platform, with support for embedded semantic metadata.

  and

  > This old hobby project of mine hasn’t been showing any signs of life for a long time now, but you’re still welcome to poke at its lifeless body with a stick if you’d like to. *- [project homepage](http://lexandera.com/mosembro/)*
- [Zirco Browser](https://code.google.com/p/zirco-browser/) - last updated February 2012, last reported issue on bugtracker July 2013

Answer (score 2):

http://code.google.com/p/zirco-browser/

Answer (score 2):

This one targets Android 4.x but can be used on Android 2.2+ as well:

https://github.com/anthonycr/Lightning-Browser

Comment: it is a mature browser.

Answer (score 1):

Here is a fresh one:
Requieres: Android 4+
https://github.com/Anasthase/TintBrowser/tree/master/src/org/tint