# fbconnect in android to publish comments on user wall

Tags: java, android, facebook

I followed the steps in http://www.mobisoftinfotech.com/blog/android/845/ but fbconnect API is a Java project but using Android package so its throwing error. So can anyone help me to complete this?

```
java.lang.enum 
Description The type java.lang.Enum cannot be resolved. It is indirectly referenced from required .class files 
Resource FBLoginButton.java 
Path /fbconnect-android/src/com/codecarpet/fbconnect 
Location line 1 
Type Java Problem
```

Comment: What? Your question doesn't make much sense, you need to provide more context.

Comment: am getting error in fbconnect/api as java.lang.enum Description Resource Path Location Type
The type java.lang.Enum cannot be resolved. It is indirectly referenced from required .class files FBLoginButton.java /fbconnect-android/src/com/codecarpet/fbconnect line 1 Java Problem

Answer (score 0):

There still doesn't seem to be enough information but it seems like your problem might be related to your configuration in Eclipse (if you're using Eclipse of course).

These answers might help figure it out:

- [Can not compile enums in Eclipse](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3811012/can-not-compile-enums-in-eclipse)
- [Android: The type java.lang.Enum cannot be resolved](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5293110/android-the-type-java-lang-enum-cannot-be-resolved)