# eclipse broken since java 6.31: Cannot find the class file for java.lang.Enum

Tags: java, eclipse, windows-7, 64-bit

I'm using Eclipse 3.6.2 on Win7 (64). Today I updated my Java 6 (JRE and JDK, both 64 bit) from 29 to 31. Now my project does not build anymore: Eclipse can not find Enum anymore. I'm aware of [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/q/5293110/821436), but I'm stuck.

These are the project settings for the libs:

[image]

And here are the system settings for the jre:

[image]

How to fix this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are (at minimum) missing the `rt.jar` library in that list, which contains the most important classes from Java. I would advise to remove this JRE definition and have Eclipse redetect it.

FYI: The Java 6 Update 30 JRE in my Eclipse lists 10 jars in its configuration; I would expect Java 6 Update 31 to have at least the same number of jars.

Comment: I fixed it: I added the _jre from the jdk_ to the list of installed jres, set it as the default, and added it to the project (properties -> java build path -> libraries -> add library -> jre system library) and removed the broken jre from the properties. Rebuild project. Now the project builds.