# Eclipse doesn't recognise enum as keyword

Tags: java, eclipse, enums

my eclipse doesn't recognise enum as keyword. I copied source code from oracle's site. And everything is good except enum part

```
public enum Day {
    SUNDAY, MONDAY, TUESDAY, WEDNESDAY,
    THURSDAY, FRIDAY, SATURDAY 
}
```

where for enum is error "enum cannot be resolved to a type"...

Do i need to import something or what? I googled for answer, but that didn't work for me...

Thank you all, 
Matija

**EDIT:** 
Eclipse still don't recognise enum as keyword. I tried all from simmilar question and still don't work...

I can't reply my question because my reputation is too low, and i can't post pictures that show **my compiler compilance level is 1.7** and i checked for all **execution enviroments that they are compatible with jre8**...

Thank you all for your time,
Matija

Comment: Code compiles fine for me. I'd guess it's something else...

Comment: Are you using eclipse? If so then check this out: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3811012/can-not-compile-enums-in-eclipse

Answer (score 1):

Check your project Java Compiler settings. Java level should be at least 1.5. That's when enum keyword was introduced.

Answer (score 1):

Please make sure that your JDK version should be **at least 1.5**. Becase ENUM keyword is introduced in this version.

You can look up you JDK version by this way:

Preferences-java-compiler-JDK compliance.