# The type java.lang.Enum cannot be resolved - Getting error after importing Java project in Eclipse

Tags: java, eclipse, eclipse-juno

I am getting the following error after importing Java project (Non Maven) in Eclipse:

```
The type java.lang.Enum cannot be resolved. It is indirectly referenced from required .class files
```

I have couple of Java classes in my project and I am getting this compilation error in the first line of this below class (In the package declaration line)

```
package com.test.utils;

public enum Currency {
    PENNY, NICKLE, DIME, QUARTER
};
```

I checked my project's Java Build Path and in the Libraries tab all the jars and JRE System Library are present. Below is the .classpath content

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
    <classpath>
        <classpathentry kind="src" path="src"/>
        <classpathentry kind="con" path="org.eclipse.jdt.launching.JRE_CONTAINER"/>
        <classpathentry kind="lib" path="lib/***.jar"/> 
        <!-- list of jars -->
        <classpathentry kind="output" path="bin"/>
   </classpath>
```

I am using eclipse JUNO

```
Eclipse Java EE IDE for Web Developers.
Version: Juno Service Release 2
Build id: 20130225-0426
```

and Java version is **jdk 1.6.0_29** and the **Compiler compliance level is 1.6** in eclipse.

**I tried the following to resolve this issue**

1. Clean the project & build the project
2. Delete and reimport the project and then again did the step 1
3. Restart eclipse from the "File" menu and again did the step 1

But none of the above worked.

Please tell me how can I get rid of this compilation error.

Comment: see this : http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3811012/can-not-compile-enums-in-eclipse

Comment: Unlike forum sites, we don't use "Thanks", or "Any help appreciated", or signatures on [so]. See "[Should 'Hi', 'thanks,' taglines, and salutations be removed from posts?](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/2950/should-hi-thanks-taglines-and-salutations-be-removed-from-posts). BTW, it's "Thanks in advance", not "Thanks in advanced".

Answer (score 6):

I had the same issue and I just restarted my IDE and it worked

Comment: I just had the same problem, and in my case I had to clean the project using Project->Clean.

Answer (score 2):

If you are using Eclipse, try running Project -> Clean

Answer (score 2):

This is happening more often for me after upgrading to the latest eclipse. Project clean does not resolve errors by itself, however after cleaning add/remove a space and resave the file does work.

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).

Answer (score 1):

Upgrading JDK package fixes the issue, after installing new JDK make sure you update your environment variables to new JDK installed path

Answer (score 0):

mvn package my project completed smoothly without errors. But eclipse IDE editor and problems panel persisted in telling me the type Enumset cannot be resolved.

I  restarted eclipse but problems panel still says type Enumset cannot be resolved.

I went to Windows-Preferences-Java-Instalked JREs
to change my default JRE from OpenJDK-17 to MSJDK-17 and the problem disappeared.  Then I changed it back to OpenJDK-17.

The Eclipse 2023-12 I am using on Linux needed a knock on its head.

Answer (score -1):

Import this java.lang.Enum. It works for me.

Comment: Classes in package `java.lang` are always imported automatically and therefore do not need to be explicitly imported. Hence no need to add `import java.lang.Enum`.